# What is the best stackexchange to ask about Amazon Web Services

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've been asking some questions on StackOverflow, and unlike most of my questions, they get a small number of views and responses. 
They deal with Amazon Web Services, and mainly with Elastic MapReduce.

My question is, what is the best stack exchange (or other group/forum) to ask for expert advice.

I've also tried the AWS forums, but I see that most questions there barely get answers.

Thanks

Comment: I take it the questions are not about programming?

Comment: They are about programming,  indeed,  but with the aws api

Comment: I have proposed a site here, if your interested please follow, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82757/cloud-computing-platforms

Comment: New Area51 proposed site for Cloud Computing (including AWS): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your case, several of your questions aren't even tagged with [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services), nor are they tagged with the language your question is about. I've fixed your questions, but that could explain why you're not seeing traffic for them.

Tagging is important to ensure the right people see your question.

We're not a good place to ask for 'expert advice'.  We are a great place to get answers to your questions.

If your questions are development based, then Stack Overflow is appropriate. IF they're Sys-admin based (managing EC2 instances, and the like), then they're appropriate for Server Fault.

The community may not have critical mass, but those are the sites that it would be appropriate for.

Comment: Thanks.  I tag the questions with 'aws',  and some of the  questions are about the api, or an sdk.  I'm just looking for functionality and don't care to much of the answer is in the Java,  python or Ruby SDK.

Comment: can't ask any questions on stackoverflow without being closed anymore is there any other site where I can get quick answers on AWS related questions?

Comment: `We're not a good place to ask for 'expert advice'. We are a great place to get answers to your questions.` Very nice distinction.