# Amazon Web Services questions? SO or SF? Both?

Tags: discussion

I'm inspired to ask this question [after seeing this question got flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036743/amazon-aws-access-rights). There are 13k questions on StackOverflow for AWS, and about 2k for ServerFault.

[This previous answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275125/659298) gives arguments for keeping them divided. [This answer from a SF mod about Docker lends support to SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276642/659298). But there's no bright line. [Mr. Atwood talks about grey areas here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283042/659298).

To me, it seems StackOverflow is usually the correct place, as these are *software* problems, generally relating to an API. Generally speaking, this seems in line with the mod's response and Atwood's response.

Comment: In my opinion it depends on what you want to do, for example a question like "how do I mitigate DDoS attacks against AWS servers?" (okay that's a terrible question but you get the point) should be on SF, where as "how do I create new AWS instances programmatically via the API?" should be on SO.

Answer (score 8):

AWS and services like it indeed touch on many different areas; a question involving it could be appropriate for anything from Webmasters.SE to ServerFault. It depends on what the main content of the question is and which audience may best be able to answer it. Asking on a different site gives the question a different context and it will be received differently:

- questions on SO are mainly about writing code and dealing with problems of said code; if you're dealing with one of the AWS APIs *programmatically* and the question involves code, this is probably the appropriate place
- questions on ServerFault are mainly about wrangling such code on a production machine and the tools used to do so; if your question involves admin-oriented features of AWS it's probably more appropriate here
- questions on Webmasters.SE are mainly about surrounding services like traffic analytics, email setup or domain management and may well touch on things such as AWS Route 53 or SES
- questions on Programmers.SE are mainly about white-boarding your architecture, which may well involve AWS

You'll have to decide what parts of AWS your question touches on most and what audience and context is most appropriate for it. Just because it contains "AWS" doesn't mean it fits into any one particular category.

Comment: With all that, I am surprised there is no aws.stackexchange.com

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Comment: Thanks for this, @deceze. You mention the case of dealing programmatically with the AWS API. What if you are writing code in AWS CloudFormation instead? Or AWS SAM, or AWS CDK? Or external DSLs like CFN DSL, SparkleFormation, Troposphere, etc? I appreciate this might seem like a silly question, but there is what I take to be a minority view in here that wants to regard anything that is "related to infrastructure" as belonging at SF.